# JAVA_HOME : The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java

When I am searching for $JAVA_HOME i am getting the below :

```
C:\Users>cd $JAVA_HOME
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have my JAVA_HOME set already :

[image]

My PATH is also set:

[image]

Comment: on linux `echo $JAVA_HOME` is the `command` to check you `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: You are on windows, not *nix.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is till ..\bin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on Windows.

So you need to do:

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%
```

instead of

```
cd $JAVA_HOME
```

Also, I recommend you to use it in your `Path` as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` (separated by `;`) such that the `Path` will be automatically updated if you change the `JAVA_HOME` value.